# Text Encoder not defined when script triggered in Power Automate

Tags: excel, typescript, power-automate

I have a script written to encode a column on my excel table in SHA256. When I run it in Excel it works perfectly. However, when I try to trigger it in Power Automate, it fails with the following error: "Text Encoder not defined."

Below is the code:

```
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let usedRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
    let lastRow = usedRange.getLastRow().getRowIndex();
    lastRow = lastRow + 1;
    
    let range = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow);
    let values = range.getValues();
    let hashedValues = await Promise.all(values.map(async (value) => {
        const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(value[0]);
        const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
        const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
        const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
        return [hashHex];
    }));
    range.setValues(hashedValues);
}
```

I've been searching high and low for an answer but couldn't find anything. Hopefully there is somebody here who can help :)